# Share datas between two apps with iOS 7 App Groups (using NSUserDefaults)

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode6, ios-app-group

Can I use method of NSUserDefaults "initWithSuitName:" in iOS 7 to share preferences between two apps with same bundle seed ID (com.my_company)?

On iOS 8.0 and later works fine, but on iOS 7.x not working, though documentation says: "Available in iOS 7.0 and later".

```
- (instancetype)initWithSuiteName:(NSString *)suitename NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 7_0) NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Any luck with this ? I'm stuck in a similar situation